# httplib2.CertificateHostnameMismatch in Google plus API

Tags: python, oauth, google-plus, httplib2

I tried to use Google plus API to go through the OAuth2 process.

I got the verifier and am going to exchange the access token, then the error occurred.

```
httplib2.CertificateHostnameMismatch: 

Server presented certificate that does not match host accounts.google.com:
```

Server presented certificate that does not match host **www.googleapis.com**

Presented certificate(Common Name) is ***.g.doubleclick.net**

Why they are different??

My code is like this:

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

CLIENT_SECRETS = 'client_secrets.json'

MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = ""

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url() 
    # the url is outputted and 
    # my browser forward to it to get the verifier

    FLOW.step2_exchange(verifier) 
    # I paste the verifier and execute this line, then error occurred.
```

Any hint?

**PS:**
my `urllib2` version is 0.7.2

Comment: if i am correct you also need to pass request_token you got in first step to get access_token

Comment: Thanks for your replying. I think Google API passed it for me, because  the code here is referred to its sample code. (but running the sample code threw the same exception)  Have you ever run the sample code successfully?

Comment: i implemented OAuth but in java not in python :(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has stumbled upon this question through having CertificateHostnameMismatch errors, I recommend that you check which python version you're using (`python --version`).

I was on Python 2.7.2 which turns out to have a few known issues/regressions re SSL certificate handling. I upgraded to the latest in the 2.7 branch, and my CertificateHostnameMismatch errors went away.